# Volume rendering: confusion with front-to-back compositing

Tags: math, graphics, rendering, volume, composite

In, for example, [GPU Gems the front-to-back compositing equation](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch39.html) (for colour) is

C'<sub>i</sub> = (1 - A'<sub>i-1</sub>)C<sub>i</sub> + C'<sub>i-1</sub>

where C'<sub>i</sub> is the output accumulated colour value; A'<sub>i-1</sub> is the accumulated alpha (opacity) value up to the *previous* voxel; C<sub>i</sub> is the colour value of the *current* voxel; and C'<sub>i-1</sub> is the accumulated colour value up to the previous voxel.

This formulation raises two questions to me:

1. Termination of front-to-back occurs once the accumulated opacity reaches approximately 1.  What, then, to do about the colour channels (RGB) that go past the maximum before the opacity limit is reached?  Do you just clamp the values between 0..255 (e.g. 500,1000,2000 would become 255,255,255), or look to the ratio between the channels (e.g. 500,1000,2000 would become 64,128,255).
2. The answer to the previous question possibly feeds into this.  The colour output of the current voxel depends on one minus the accumulated opacity.  What if the accumulated opacity is zero *and* the current voxel's opacity is zero? - the output is a completely opaque voxel, since (1 - A'<sub>i-1</sub>) = 1, even though it is supposedly a transparent voxel!?

Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: formula is recursive, how do you get A'_0 and C'_0?

Comment: @Eugeny89: good question! I have no idea and can find no reference to tell me!  I assume 0 for both (i.e. transparent black).

Comment: It might be important to know if the colors are (or should be) pre-multiplied by alpha.  If pre-multiplied, then they shouldn't max out until the opacity does.

Comment: @Adrian: Ah, that's interesting.  I did find things started to make sense if I multiplied with the current voxel's opacity, as well as one minus the accumulated opacity.  However, none of the documentation I found does it that way,

Comment: Yes normally you'd start with A(0)=0 and C(0)=0.  I know another reference which gives the equation as C'(i)=(1-A'(i-1))*C(i)*A(i)+C'(i-1), which would be the non-premultiplied-alpha version.  I find the non-premultiplied version is more intuitive; it's saying only as much voxel color bleeds into the ray as there is material present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A and C should be in the range 0-1.  (If you're using unsigned bytes as the representation, divide by 255.0, but note that for some volume rendering application areas this will give you insufficient control over small alpha/low opacity regions to really be satisfactory.  These days it's generally just easier to compute using floats from the outset).  It turns out that the alpha and color values can never escape outside this range using the your formulas.
2. The sequence for the ray alpha A' is A'(i) = (1-A'(i-1)).A(i) + A'(i-1) (where A(i) is the voxel alpha), so if your accumulated ray starts with A' zero, and passes through a transparent (zero A) voxel, the ray now has A' = (1-0)*0+0, which is still zero as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems to clear things up mostly. On point (2) though: from your answer it seems that you accumulate alpha *before* colour, then use A'(i) rather than A'(i-1) when calculating the colour contribution of the current voxel?

Comment: Er, sorry... don't understand what you mean.  With the expression in '2' above, I'd use say C'(i)=(1-A'(i-1))*C(i)*A(i)+C'(i-1), (see comment on your question) so I don't see where A'(i) comes into it ?  The "'"-primed quantities are the ray integrals, the un-primed A & C are the voxel values from the volume dataset.

Comment: Ah, I misread your answer I think (read A' as C').  So am I correct in saying that the formula in my original question only works if you assume pre-multiplied alpha?  Pretty sure it doesn't mention that in GPU Gems, which is harsh.

Answer (score 0):

A and C should be between 0 and 1.  Use pre-multiplied alpha; you will have no overflow issues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by pre-multiplied alpha?  Do you mean multiply all the voxels with their respective alpha value before proceeding with composition?  This would be equivalent to timday's comment, formulating the equation as: C'(i)=(1-A'(i-1))*C(i)*A(i)+C'(i-1) .

Comment: Yes, essentially. To go from the conventional 4 channel color format (C) to pre-multiplied alpha (C'): `C'_rgb = C_rgb * C_a` and `C'_a = C_a`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, let's belive that C and A are between 0 and 1. as one can see sequense `C'(i) = [1 - A'_(i+1)]C(i) + C'(i-1)` is grows with grow of `i`. I think C is not color (of RGB or whatever model). Maybe it's 'greyness' of some voxel. I.e. if voxel has many voxels in front of it it should be more grey then top voxels.

So my assumption is that C_i does not describe color dirrectly. It tells us how grey we should make color of some voxel.

forgive me for my poor English and fill free to re-ask if something is not clear.

BTW: if you belive me C_0 (greyness of top voxel) should be 1, and A_0 should be 0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can treat each colour channel of RGB seperately, as if doing multiple grey levels at once, then combine to a final colour...?